# Saving the highlighting of current row in Oracle Apex Classic Report after closing the dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Good evening to everybody here!

At this moment I'm working with one page in Oracle Apex (version 4.2.6.00.03). It consists of two Classic Reports — the first is a "master" one, and the second contains "details" of the former. Also there are several buttons for performing actions of inserting/updating/deleting the data. My purpose is not only to make the actions work and "details" report to refresh on choosing the row from the "master" one (I've completed these tasks), but also to manage to save the highlighting of reports' rows even after performing the actions (not only just refreshing the page).

Now I'll explain what I've already done. One can choose the row (and simultaneously highlight it) by means of the script I put in every Report's footer and it looks like this:

```
<script>
$(".t20data","#master_report").live("click",function(){
  chooseMST($(this).find("span.MASTER").attr("id"));
});
</script>
```

There *master_report* is an ID of "master" report's region and *MASTER* stands for span class, in which I wrap all the cells in report to keep the value of row's ID. The function *chooseMST* is this:

```
function chooseMST(docID){
  $.post('wwv_flow.show',
         {'p_request'      : 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=SET_MASTER',
          'p_flow_id'      : $v('pFLowId'),
          'p_flow_step_id' : $v('pFlowStepId'),
          'p_instance'     : $v('pInstance'),
          'x01'            : docID},
         function(data){
          //refreshes "details" report
          $('#detail_report').trigger('apexrefresh');
          //deletes color from all the rows of "master" report
          $(".t20data","#master_report").parent("tr").children().css("background-color","#F2F2F5");
          //highlights the chosen row in "master" report
          $("#" + String(docID)).parent("td").parent("tr").children().css("background-color","#A3BED8");
         }
        );
}
```

The action (say, AJAX callback) *SET_MASTER* is this:

```
begin
  --clears the choice from "detail" report
  APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE(P_NAME  => 'P400_DETAIL_RN'
                             ,P_VALUE => NULL);
  --makes the choice from "master" one
  APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE(P_NAME  => 'P400_MASTER_RN'
                             ,P_VALUE => APEX_APPLICATION.G_X01);
end;
```

To say about refreshing the page, I solved the problem of clearing the hidden items *P400_DETAIL_RN* and *P400_MASTER_RN* by having a process which goes before header with this PL/SQL code:

```
begin
  :P400_DETAIL_RN := APEX_UTIL.GET_NUMERIC_SESSION_STATE(P_ITEM  => 'P400_DETAIL_RN');
  :P400_MASTER_RN := APEX_UTIL.GET_NUMERIC_SESSION_STATE(P_ITEM  => 'P400_MASTER_RN');
end;
```

and the Javascript function *recolorRows* which is executed every time the page is loading:

```
function recolorRows(){
  $(".t20data","#master_report").parent("tr").children().css("background-color","#F2F2F5");
  if($("P400_MASTER_RN").val() != "") $("#" + String($("P400_MASTER_RN").val())).parent("td").parent("tr").children().css("background-color","#A3BED8");
  $(".t20data","#detail_report").parent("tr").children().css("background-color","#F2F2F5");
  if($("P400_DETAIL_RN").val() != "") $("#" + String($("P400_DETAIL_RN").val())).parent("td").parent("tr").children().css("background-color","#A3BED8");
}
```

The code concerning rows from "details" report is alike, so let me omit this part. Problems begin for me from performing the actions of manipulating the data. Here is the function which opens the dialog window for inserting or updating the row chosen in "master" report:

```
function MST_open(action){
  //the part of code which finds out with what parameteres we should call the dialog window
  $("#dialogFrame").attr("src",stringToCall);
  $("#dialogWindow").dialog({
    title:windowName,
    modal:true,
    width:500,
    height:500,
    resizable:true,
    close:reloadMST //the action on closing the window
  });
}
```

The code of *reloadMST* looks as follows:

```
function reloadMST(){
  $("master_report").trigger('apexrefresh');
  $("detail_report").trigger('apexrefresh');
}
```

And the Javascript function, which executes in the dialog window on the certain button click (for example, "Update"), is this:

```
function mstUpdate(){
  $.post('wwv_flow.show',
         {'p_request'      : 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=MASTER_UPDATE',
          'p_flow_id'      : $v('pFLowId'),
          'p_flow_step_id' : $v('pFlowStepId'),
          'p_instance'     : $v('pInstance'),
          'x01'            : apex.item("P402_SNAME").getValue()},
         function(data){
          //returns the ID of updated row in "msg" part of "res" variable
          var res = eval("(" + data + ")");
          if(res.status != "OK"){
            //the code which catches the error, if it appears
          } else {
            parent.MST_close(res.msg);
          }
         }
        );
}
```

where *MST_close* is this:

```
function MST_close(docID){
  $("#dialogWindow").dialog("close");
  //see this function above
  chooseMST(docID);
}
```

So, this is a chain of Javascript and PL/SQL actions, which concerns the updating of the row from "master" report. The actions of inserting/updating/deleting the data work great, but I can't say the same about the saving of rows' color. The latter works good while I'm only choosing rows or refresh the page, but after performing, for example, the updating, the current row loses its highlighting. By debugging (say, adding the function *console.log* in Javascript code) I found out that the  chain of actions, which must lead to saving the highlighting, executes nominally, but it looks like refreshing the report either goes **after** coloring or just prevents the latter.

Thus, my question is this: is there any way to save the highlight of the current row even after opening and closing the child dialog window?

Comment: For the source of the 2 hidden items (P400_DETAIL_RN and P400_MASTER_RN) do you have at as 'Only when current value in session state is null'? Did you explored the option to add a Dynamic Action on event Dialog Closed where you can set the two hidden items again?

Comment: For my two hidden items I have option "Only when current value in session state is null". To say about Dynamic Action, at this moment I don't quite understand what you mean. Maybe, I should have said it before, but I have _not_ problems with saving the values of my hidden items (and due to this the highlight remains after refreshing the page), but I have problem with the fact that after closing the dialog window the highlighting disappears. In other words, I need to understand more things about Javascript functions, while Dynamic Actions is only a wrapping for them. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that after you update the value of a record in the modal window you refresh the data in the 2 reports in the main page and so you lose the highlight.

To fix this try to create a **Dynamic Action** on the event **After Refresh** on **Region: Your Classic Reports** that will execute the javascript function `recolorRows()`. You can also do it with javascript. The main ideea is that after you refresh the 2 reports (using `reloadMST()` or other method) you must trigger `recolorRows()`.

Comment: Recently I've tried to create Dynamic Action for each report, as you advised me, and I rewrote _recolorRows()_ function that it could recolor distinct report or both ones. It helped me only in some way. The "master" report works _almost_ fine (except the fact that after closing the dialog window the highlighting "runs" to the previously chosen row), but in the "details" report the saving of the highlight is floating - sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. Also I'd like to make my page in such way that the inserted row could also become highlighted, but I have no idea how t do that.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine what exactly is happening on your pages. If you can please try to create or import the 2 pages on apex.oracle.com so we can better understand what you have. Regarding highlight of the inserted row i think you need to create another hidden item where on dialog close you insert the ID of the new record so that you can highlight it with javascript.

Comment: unfortunately, I have no opportunity to copy my pages into apex.oracle.com, but is there in this site an open database (maybe with EXAMPLE tablespace)? The absence of the tables I use in my pages is not fundamental for me - I just need any two tables to recreate my example.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Cristian_I, very much. I've recently solved my problem. My mistake was that I hadn't done the hidden items binding in HTML-code - in other words, by means of Javascript only. Watching the behaviour of the hidden items, I'd discovered that when I tried to find their value with the help of jQuery function $("#hidden_item").val(), I got the **previous** values, but not the **current** ones (i.e. session state values). So that's why I had the highlighting unstable.

In addition to Dynamic Actions triggering right after refreshing the reports, I should have just add these strings to my function *chooseMST* before the "coloring" code itself:

```
$("#P400_MASTER_RN").val(docID); //binding to exact string
```

and

```
$("#P400_DETAIL_RN").val(""); //clearing the choice in the "details" report.
```

Due to this the problem with recoloring the rows have just gone away! Thus, now my page works excellent: the highlighting is stable, and even new rows are highlighted right after inserting them.